# Windows 10 Photo View Next button doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, windows-photo-viewer

So when viewing a folder with pictures on your computer in Windows, you could always right click a picture file and then click Preview. This opens it in the Windows Photo Viewer. You could then immediately click the next icon and it would bring you to the next picture in the folder.

Now in Windows 10 the Next button is never active and doesn't work, so you have to close the picture, and then right click the next one, and preview again. Even the play slideshowbutton (the button in the middle) doesn't work.

[image]

Anyone know how to get it working, or maybe an alternate better solution?

Comment: I believe this is a bug (err, limitation) in Photo Viewer. Can you try again, but this time in a folder that has ONLY picture files. Let us know how that goes.

Comment: Hm, yes it worked when only pictures were in the folder. I guess that's good to know, but I've already installed an open source program called ImageGlass which is essentially the same thing - and it doesn't care there are other files in the folder. Just use Open With or set it as the default program and double click.

Comment: Excellent, confirms the bug then.  You're doing the right thing by using 3rd party software.  Don't count on MS fixing this bug any time soon (if at all). I'll answer the question, feel free to mark it correct ;-)

Comment: [Fix: Windows Photo Viewer Previous Next Buttons Disabled and Arrow Keys Do not Work](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-photo-viewer-previous-next-buttons-disabled-arrow-keys-not-work-fix/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug (err, limitation?) in Photo Viewer where, in certain cases, the presence of non-picture files (in the same folder as the pictures you're viewing) prevents the forward/back/slideshow buttons from working. Under the hood, Photo Viewer may believe there is only one picture when there are more.

Don't count on Microsoft fixing the issue any time soon, if at all. There are plenty of excellent 3rd-party alternatives that will see you right.